# pgfplots' axis with different scale size

Tags: pgfplots

my MWE as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, unit vector ratio=4 1]
    \addplot[draw=red, domain=0:1, smooth, samples=100] {2*exp(x)-x-1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but why the scale size between 0 and 1 is smaller than others ?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale between 0 and 1 (on the y-axis I assume) is not smaller, but y = 0 is simply not shown. You can force the y-axis to start at 0 with `ymin = 0`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, unit vector ratio=4 1,ymin=0]
    \addplot[draw=red, domain=0:1, smooth, samples=100] {2*exp(x)-x-1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works, many thanks